# How to define different options for multiple arrays in one function?

Tags: jquery

this is my first stackoverflow question and I hope I didn't miss any relevant topics, however I didn't find an answer yet. I've been fiddeling around with a (probably simple) jquery task and I'm stuck. And, ehem, of course I'm a newbie to jquery, so please be kind :-)

I'd like to do a simple flashing words cloudy thing, where different groups of words (list items) fade in and out with *individual delays*. I got this to work with a simple function which I call three times, for each of the three groups. I'd like to know if there's a way to combine these three functions, but still defining an individual delay for each array of words.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alani/eHthD/

Maybe there's no way to put everything in one function and it's totally ok to use the long version? I don't know. It just seems totally inefficient to me...

For quick view here's one of my functions:

```
var wordIndex = -1;

(function () {

    var words1 = $(".cloud1");
    function showNextWord() {

        ++wordIndex;
        words1.eq(wordIndex % words1.length)
            .fadeIn(500)
            .delay(1000)
            .fadeOut(1000, showNextWord);
    }

    showNextWord();

})();
```

And this is part of my list

```
<ul>
<li class="cloud1">smoke</li>
<li class="cloud1">denim</li>
<li class="cloud1">eyebrow</li>

<li class="cloud2">angle</li>
<li class="cloud2">staple</li>
<li class="cloud2">basket</li>
...
```

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Did you want random delays for every element or just some constant for each list?

Comment: Some constant delay is totally ok. It would interest me, how to add a random delay ("Math.random()" I guess), but I don't need it to build my cloud. I updated my fiddle, btw http://jsfiddle.net/alani/hnzag/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a slightly more complex version that, however, allows you to just add new elements to the document without having to update the JavaScript.

Here's the code:

```
var wordIndexes = {};

$(function() {
    num_groups = 0;
    $('ul.cloud').each(function() {
        var group = $(this).data('group');
        wordIndexes[group] = -1;
        num_groups = (group > num_groups) ? group : num_groups;
    });

    for (n=1; n <= num_groups; ++n) {
        (function(i) {
          var words = $('ul.cloud[data-group="' + i + '"] li');

          function showNextWord() {
            ++wordIndexes[i];
            words.eq(wordIndexes[i] % words.length)
                .fadeIn(500)
                .delay(i * 1000)
                .fadeOut(1000, showNextWord);
          }
          showNextWord();
        })(n);
    }
});
```

The CSS:

```
.cloud li {
    display: none;
}
.cloud[data-group="2"] li {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
.cloud[data-group="3"] li{
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

And the HTML should be something like:

```
<ul class="cloud" data-group="1">
  <li>smoke</li>
  <li>denim</li>
  ...
</ul>

<ul class="cloud" data-group="2">
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V5EFn/

You could optionally add a data field for the delay, or any other configuration parameters you see fit.

Comment: Oh thank u. This really is kinda complex and I'll need some time to understand how it works :-) The delay for each group will be a multiple of 1000 (1*1000, 2*1000, 3*1000) according to the data-group, right?

Comment: Yep. Otherwise, you can just set a `data-` attribute for them, if you want to have more freedom. Or even use random delays...

Comment: There seems to be a little problem - sometimes, not always, the same word is flashing two or three times before changing to the next list item. Could you have a look again? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but it seems to happen with your example as well.

Comment: Code updated. You have to use separate counters for each group, otherwise the different delays will mess the whole thing up.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
var flash = function (jq, fadein, wait, fadeout) {

    var quotes = $(jq);
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {

        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(fadein)
            .delay(wait)
            .fadeOut(fadeout, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

};

flash(".cloud1", 500, 700, 500);
flash(".cloud2", 500, 800, 500);
flash(".cloud3", 500, 900, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was fast. This version does flash each group: http://jsfiddle.net/alani/hnzag/ 

But I still need to define different delays, so that they don't flash at the same time but one after another, irregularely. Like in my first fiddle.

Comment: THANK U NOLO! That's it. Now I know how it works. Cool. And so fast :-)))

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do what you want with out making the code more complicated. What you can try however is having a common function to do the work ...

```
function beginCloud($obj, delay) {

    var wordIndex = -1;
    var showNextWord = function() {

        ++wordIndex;
        $obj.eq(wordIndex % $obj.length)
            .fadeIn(500)
            .delay(delay)
            .fadeOut(1000, showNextWord);
    }

    showNextWord();

}

beginCloud( $('.cloud1', 1000) );
beginCloud( $('.cloud2', 2000) );
beginCloud( $('.cloud3', 3000) );
```